# list posts by US states from posts_meta table

Tags: wordpress, listings

i am working on a prison database WordPress site, i want to display all US states on a page and then on click of a state should take you to a page to list all prisons of that state and once the prison is clicked should show the prison data

each prison is stored as post and prison information is stored in the posts_meta table

the rest of the site works fine apart from listing of prisons by state, i am unable to implement the 3 page process and i am new to WordPress as well

Answer (score 0):

I belive you should better to use states as [Taxonomy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Taxonomies).